# No sound on Asus Zenbook UX391UA with HDA Intel PCH

Tags: sound

I got this new laptop, installed 18.04 on it, and so far I can't get the audio to work (both internal/external speakers). The card exists, and in audio settings it seems normal and microphone works.

```
0 [PCH]:
HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
HDA Intel PCH at 0xec228000 irq 134
```

In another question, the suggestion was to do this but it didn't work for me:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf 
add line : options snd-hda-intel model=pch position_fix=1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can confirm that! But sound through Bluetooth boxes/headphones works. Does yours right top corner around the power button run also very hot on normal tasks? This issue is also mentioned [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1784485) and [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/alc294-analog-audio-card-detected-but-no-sound-internaly-or-headphones/54089/13).

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for replying. I ended up giving up. I think the issue is coming from the laptop itself, we tried so many things and nothing worked, but we didn't try bluetooth. I then installed Fedora, got some audio, but after 10sec the audio died. We concluded about the hardware because all distro we tried didn't work, but the bluetooth worked. USB-C headphones too.

Comment: Still no sound with Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: I've opened another issue regarding this notebook. It's about overheating. Would be very helpful, if you could share your experience here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087672/unusually-hot-asus-ux391ua

Comment: Does shutting down the computer completely (not restart. an actual cold bootup) and booting straight to linux fix the problem? it does for me on a very similar issue

Comment: @Hilikus That makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

After some help from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1784485 I finally fixed the problem.

It requires new kernel and some manual patching.

## First download kernel source and extract it

```
wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.19.12.tar.xz
tar Jxf linux-4.19.12.tar.xz
```

## Install necessary packages

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libncurses-dev bison flex \
             libssl-dev libelf-dev
```

## Copy kernel config

```
cd linux-4.19.12/
cp -v /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
make defconfig
```

## Add support for UX391UA

Add line to file `sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c`

```
SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x1043, 0x10a1, "ASUS UX391UA", ALC294_FIXUP_ASUS_SPK)
```

In patch format

```
--- patch_realtek.c.bck 2018-12-21 14:15:25.000000000 +0100
+++ patch_realtek.c 2018-12-30 16:13:23.970326312 +0100
@@ -6584,6 +6584,7 @@
    SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x1043, 0x13b0, "ASUS Z550SA", ALC256_FIXUP_ASUS_MIC),
    SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x1043, 0x1427, "Asus Zenbook UX31E", ALC269VB_FIXUP_ASUS_ZENBOOK),
    SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x1043, 0x14a1, "ASUS UX533FD", ALC294_FIXUP_ASUS_SPK),
+    SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x1043, 0x10a1, "ASUS UX391UA", ALC294_FIXUP_ASUS_SPK),
    SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x1043, 0x1517, "Asus Zenbook UX31A", ALC269VB_FIXUP_ASUS_ZENBOOK_UX31A),
    SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x1043, 0x16e3, "ASUS UX50", ALC269_FIXUP_STEREO_DMIC),
    SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x1043, 0x1a13, "Asus G73Jw", ALC269_FIXUP_ASUS_G73JW),
```

## Build kernel

This command must be executed in top directory of linux source.

```
make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom
```

## Install new kernel and reboot

```
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.19.12-custom_4.19.12-custom-1_amd64.deb \
             linux-image-4.19.12-custom_4.19.12-custom-1_amd64.deb
reboot
```

Comment: Hi Pawel! This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Comment: @abu_bua Installing a new and patched kernel does indeed solves it. What makes you think it does not?

Answer (score 1):

A more comfortable way is to install the [Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility](https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu) (UKUU) and upgrade to the v5.0-rc1 kernel. The stable v4.20 doesn't include the fix for the Asus UX391UA, as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1784485).