# Unusually hot Asus UX391UA

Tags: asus, overheating, temperature

My newly bought Asus ZenBook S UX391UA runs unusually hot with Ubuntu 18.10. Even in the BIOS the temperature is around 70° after a cold boot, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QPJL.png). After some minutes it normally [raises](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y34QG.png) up to 74°-75°. I have a normal room temperature around 21°-23°. The notebook itself is clean.

At some point the preinstalled `thermald` daemon even forcefully shuts down Ubuntu, preventing it from overheating. Before the shutdown, usually the following appears in the logs:

> Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled

The only solution I've found is to remove the `thermald` package. Didn't observe any undesirable side effects so far.

My BIOS' [version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E57cb.png) is 204. Strangely, ASUS only offers the 202 version on their [site](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-S-UX391UA/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

Does somebody observe the same? Especially the high temperatures in the BIOS.

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/391474/stop-cpu-from-overheating/875872#875872

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have the same. To avoid this I just install TLP and change in configuration

```
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_AC=performance
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT=powersave
CPU_HWP_ON_AC=default
CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_AC=80
CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_BAT=50
CPU_BOOST_ON_AC=0
CPU_BOOST_ON_BAT=0
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_AC=balance-performance
```

And now my temperature not raising higher then 70 C.

BTW I have same issue on another Asus UX490UA, same solution helps

Comment: My issue is about the UX391UA, not UX490UA. Since your approach with `tlp` applies to other notebooks as well and therefore isn't model-specific, I won't mark it is a legitimate answer for now.

Comment: It is not single model specific, maybe I did not write it clearly. I have both UX391UA and UX490UA, both have same issue. Same solution helps on both of them.