# No Sound in Asus Zenbook 14 UX433FA after installing ubuntu 18.10

Tags: sound, asus

I installed Ubuntu 18.10 in my computer along side windows 10. The sound works fine in Windows but not in Ubuntu.
I have tried the following [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098262/no-sound-in-asus-zenbook-14-ux433fn-after-installing-ubuntu-18-04) suggestion but nothing seems to work.

I will appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing a "real" shutdown from Windows 10? Unless you run specific commands in Windows or disable the "fast shut down" feature you're never actually turning off Windows but instead putting it into a sleep state. https://www.howtogeek.com/349114/shutting-down-doesnt-fully-shut-down-windows-10-but-restarting-it-does/

Comment: Take a look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1784485 comment 36 and maybe https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056909/no-sound-on-asus-zenbook-ux391ua-with-hda-intel-pch/1058122 (instruction how to compile kernel)

Comment: does the trackpad/keypad still work as both? or just as a trackpad?

Comment: install kernel 5 on your ubuntu... it works well... how to install kernel 5 :
you can use ukuu or install manually by downloading it... http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/03/linux-kernel-5-0-released-how-install-ubuntu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution by updating the kernel using ukuu

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

Open ukuu from the Activities and then select and install Linux 4.19.11

reboot

Enjoy the sound.

Comment: This brought my sound back but now it's distorted. Any ideas?