# No sound on Ubuntu 18.10 with Asus ZenBook UX433F

Tags: sound

I have installed in dual boot Ubuntu 18.10 on a Asus ZenBook  but I got no sound with speakers and headohnes.

Comment: I've found an older question that might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105718/no-sound-in-asus-zenbook-14-ux433fa-after-installing-ubuntu-18-10

Comment: Yes, thanks. This solution actually worked for me ( I have installed kernel 4.19.43 with ukuu).